# Global Variable in shell script

Tags: bash, shell

I would like to make `z` a global variable in the following code:

```
#!/bin/bash                                                                                                                          
z=0;
find $1 -name "*.txt" | \
while read file
do
  i=1;
  z=`expr $i + $z`;
  echo "$z";
done
echo "$z";
```

The last statement always outputs "0". Why?

Comment: You could use `z=$(( z + i ))` or `(( z += i ))` to about calling out to `expr`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Pipes start a new subshell.](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/024)

Comment: so how can I get last value inside z ?

Answer (score 1):

The simple way to translate

```
find ...  | while read ...; done
```

to a form without pipes is using [process substitution](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Process-Substitution):

```
while read ...; done < <(find ...)
```

Readability suffers somewhat.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why this happened, but the problem is caused by the pipe.

If you do it like this

```
#!/bin/bash                                                                                                                          
    z=0;
    for f in `find $1 -name "*.txt"`
    do
    i=1;
    z=`expr $i + $z`;
    echo "$z";
    done
    echo "$z";
```

then $z will not be zero.